# Webform created date

Tags: 8, webforms

Is it possible to see the date a webform was created?

We use webforms extensively and sometimes they have very similar names, we want to be able to see when a webform was created to be able to determine which is the correct one.

This doesn't appear to be in the webform object nor in any db tables.

Comment: I don't think so. You also can't see the created date of a node type or vocabulary I think.

Comment: Webforms are configuration entities, and as such do not store their date. In the past I have utilized the Category/Tagging field on the Webform's general configuration to give them something arbitrary to look up by, perhaps you could just make it a best practice to type in a datestamp (YYYYMMDD) into that field when you create new webforms.